# Bench test using siege by using dynamic url generated using bash script

Tags: php, bash, terminal, apachebench, siege

I want to bench test my website with 1M requests with different urls using siege, I need to know can I create a bash script to do a random loop or php script to read urls from database and create dynamic urls and give this urls to siege command to perform bench test ?

for example I have this type of banner_sizes :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "size": "normal_x970h90",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "size": "normal_x234h60",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "size": "normal_x468h60",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "size": "normal_x300h600",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "size": "normal_x120h600",
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "size": "normal_x160h600",
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "size": "normal_x120h240",
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "size": "normal_x300h250",
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "size": "normal_x250h250",
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "size": "normal_x600h300",
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "size": "normal_x728h90",
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "size": "normal_x300h100",
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "size": "normal_x125h125",
    }
]
```

And also I have these id's :

```
 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#915}
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#926}
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#924}
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#913}
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#929}
  ]
  5 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#862}
  ]
  6 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#863}
  ]
  7 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#864}
  ]
  8 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#865}
  ]
  9 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#928}
  ]
  10 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#927}
  ]
  11 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#917}
  ]
  12 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#918}
  ]
  13 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#899}
  ]
  14 => array:1 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID {#898}
  ]
]
```

I need to create these type of url using above info :

```
www.example.come/api/is/normal_x234h60/899
www.example.com/api/is/normal_x600h300/898
```

and more like this.

Is there a way to create this urls and put them in txt file and then run my siege command :

```
   siege -c10000 -b -t30m -f urls.txt
```

Or using apache ab bench test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for this matter, I've created a php file which it connects to mysql and mongodb database and read the data, then in a nested for loop I created those urls I needed and stored them in txt file.
then I just needed to run the siege command :

```
siege -c10000 -b -t30m -f urls.txt
```

but because of siege issue with big size requests I created a bash script which will read each line of urls.txt file and runs an apache ab test using each url to stress test with dynamic urls my application.

php code to create urls :

```
        $seats = Seat::where('status', 'ACTIVE')->get();
        $s_count = Seat::where('status', 'ACTIVE')->count();


        $bs = Banners::where('status', 'enable')->get();
        $bs_count = Banners::where('status', 'enable')->count();

        $url = Config('conf.APP_PATH') . "/api/is/";
        $url_array = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $s_count; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $bs_count; $j++) {
                $url_array[] = $url . $bs[$j]['size'] . "/" . $seats[$i]['_id']."\n";
            }
        }


        File::put('./url.txt',$url_array);
```

bash script to run multiple bench test :

```
while read LINE; do
   cmnd="./ab -n10000 -c100 "
   cmnd=${cmnd}"$LINE"
   eval $cmnd
   cmnd=''
done < urls.txt
```